# Can't start a GIT build on Teamcity

Tags: git, teamcity

I'm trying to configure a build with Teamcity and GIT. Getting the following error during checkout -

```
Failed to perform checkout on agent: Unable to run git at path C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\
```

I've installed msysgit and git extensions and the above path contains git.exe. Any ideas?

Comment: I even tried to copy the git.exe to another directory and updated the path in the VCS Settings. Same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution. I was using the agentside checkout on Teamcity version 7.1.5 with GIT 1.8.3 while using the password authentication.

The Repo URL was missing .git in the end. Being a noob on GIT, didn't realize that was needed and was using SVN style URL. Adding .git resolved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same error after switching `VCS Checkout Mode` to `Automatically on Agent`

Explicitly populating `Path to Git` with the full executable path in the `VCS Root` solved it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue because I forgot to install git on the agent.

The solution was simply to install git and restart the agent.